# When does Core Data flush to disk?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios5

I use Core Data in my application, and discovered some odd behavior of the simulator: When I add some data to Core Data in my app and quits the simulator using the "stop" button in XCode (or just press Cmd-Q) immediately, the data is not stored in the database the next time I start the simulator. After some testing, I found out, that the data is stored to disk:

- immediately if I press the home button. (Almost - it *is* possible to quit the application before data is stored if quitting very fast.)
- If I let the application run for some time (at least about 20 seconds) after adding data.

It does not help to call [NSManagedObjectContext save:]. The behavior is the same.

So my question is: What is the reason for this kind of behavior? Are there any way to force flushing to disk before quitting? And are there any risk that I can loose data this way when running on a device (personally, I do not see any, except a force close, but the odd behavior bothers me a bit)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're probably using nested context's. If your context has a parent context, calling `-save:` will just save to that context, not to the file system.

Nested context are (usually) used to safely use a context on a background queue, and allowing a foreground context to save without having to incur the overhead of saving to the file system. The save to the file system will happen on a background queue and not block the main thread.

Comment: That is correct. Calling `[context save:&error]; [[context parentContext] save:&error];` does the job, and the data is saved to disk immediately. I have to do both calls (which is reasonable), but surprisingly it does not matter if I call save on context or parentContext first! Do you have an explanation on that?

Comment: BTW, as a note for others: I did not set up nested contexts myself, so this is going on "behind the scenes".

Comment: You must *not* call `[[context parentContext] save:&error]` on the thead of `context` that is not thread safe (as I pointed out). You need to call `[[context parentContext] performBlock:^(){ [[context parentContext] save:NULL] }];` (or the like)

Answer (score 9):

Stopping the *simulator* with the stop button in Xcode is probably the same as smashing your iPhone with a hammer (but preserving the SSD).  Basically, your app and everything else just stops.  There's no reasonable way to ensure that data is saved when that happens.

Answer (score 0):

I too have been wrestling with this for a very long time and Daniel Eggert's answer under (2) above is the first - and only - useful answer I have found on the internet. I presume JRV is using the NSManagedDocumentContext from a UIManagedDocument. If this is the case then Apple's 'default' saving method is incomplete! Having adopted Daniel Eggert's solution my data is now preserving perfectly and is also immune to a simulator 'STOP' gesture. I recommend Daniel Eggert's answer under (2) above to anyone else wishing to write resilient code in this case.