# Multiple Managed Object Context in main app and extension

Tags: ios, serviceextension

My app and its extension are using a sharing database through app group, and using different NSManagedObjectContext because extension cannot use NSManagedObjectContext from main app.

The problem is, when I change data in main app and call NSManagedObjectContext save, I can't get newest data in extension immediately (I tried set stalenessInterval to 0 and call refreshAllObjects in extension before get data but it's not work too). I can only get newest data after a few minutes, sometimes hours.

How can I get newest data from main app immediately?

Comment: Have you made sure the file is actually written with the updated context - context save may not push changes to the file.

Comment: @Volker I don't get it, what do you mean "updated context"?

Comment: updated context: you change managed objects or add new ones -> the moc is update, but not necessarily written to file.

Comment: @Volker I don't manage it, so how to make moc push change to the file immediately?

Comment: maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428351/when-does-core-data-flush-to-disk

Comment: Well that's not true in my situation because I'm not using nested context